# Using the Ethereum storage for document certification

Tags: go-ethereum, storage, certification

I am working on a Document certification platform that is based on ethereum and I wanted to know if it is possible to use the ethereum storage as a way to keep the records of documents.

I know that the ethereum storage is not immutable like the blockchain is.

Comment: I don't see how my question is related to storing large files on a smart contract. I am asking if the ethereum storage is usable as a data certification record holder.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the storage in smart contracts immutable if you don't provide a function to update / delete the value in the contract.

Probably you would want to just store a hash (i.e. fingerprint) of the document rather than the whole document on-chain. You could store the document on IPFS and then a reference (which is just a hash of the document) to it's IPFS location on-chain perhaps.